# How to used the trained model?

Tags: orange

I am new to Orange DM tool, and try to perform a protoype on ML

Step 1: Create the trained model, and save it. File has two columns, Product description as a feature and Classification (manually classified each record) as target column

[image]

Step 2: Use the trained module and predict the classification. 
[image]

Question 1: See the error, and not able to understand the reason because input file is subset of file used in step 1.

[image]

Question 2: Classification column was added manually for training purpose; Here, How do I add the classification column dynamically and let the model fill the classification value and where it is not able do leave it blank?

Question 3: How do I automate this via command line? or you recommend user run the file manually via Orange GUI?

Workflow:
a) drop the file in the c:\temp
b) run a batch file which will take the input file and apply the classification
c) two files - 1) classified file 2) mis-classification file

Hope this make sense? Let me know if you need more info.

Really appreciate your guidance.

Rahim